# DataSourceResult in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

When i was worked in `Asp.net Mvc` , for paging data use `KendoUi`.this code use in `Asp.net Mvc Web api`

```
 public DataSourceResult Get(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage)
        {
            var request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSourceRequest>(
                requestMessage.RequestUri.ParseQueryString().GetKey(0)
            );
            WebApplicationDbContext db = new WebApplicationDbContext();
            var list = db.Product.ToList();
            return list.AsQueryable()
                       .ToDataSourceResult(request.Take, request.Skip, request.Sort, request.Filter);
        }
```

And now working with `Asp.net Core` when i was use this code , it doesn't work.
in the error list show to me this error

> 'Uri' does not contain a definition for 'ParseQueryString' and no
>   extension method 'ParseQueryString' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Uri' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

How can i use this code in `Asp.net Core`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the `HttpRequestMessage requestMessage` parameter. Then remove the `requestMessage.RequestUri.ParseQueryString().GetKey(0)` part and replace it with:

```
var rawQueryString = this.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.ToString();
// PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities
var rawQueryStringKeyValue = QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(rawQueryString).FirstOrDefault();
var dataString = Uri.UnescapeDataString(rawQueryStringKeyValue.Key); // this is your received JSON data from Kendo UI
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your [ https://github.com/VahidN/KendoUI.Core.Samples ]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to deserialize the request. I normally pass `request` to `ToDataSourceResult` extension method.

*[For example,](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Presentation/Asp.Web/Areas/Administration/Controllers/SettingsController.cs#L42)*

```
public JsonResult Get([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
   var db = new WebApplicationDbContext();
   return db.Product.ToDataSourceResult(request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [VahidN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298573/vahidn)
This project has helped me a lot 
[KendoUI.Core.Samples](https://github.com/VahidN/KendoUI.Core.Samples)

Im use this code in `Controller`

```
 public DataSourceResult GetProducts()
        {
            var dataString = this.HttpContext.GetJsonDataFromQueryString();
            var request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSourceRequest>(dataString);

            var list = ProductDataSource.LatestProducts;
            return list.AsQueryable()
                       .ToDataSourceResult(request.Take, request.Skip, request.Sort, request.Filter);
        }
```

And use this code in `chstml`

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<!--Right to left grid-->
<div class="k-rtl">
    <div id="report-grid"></div>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var productsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "@Url.Action("GetProducts", "Sample03")",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        type: 'GET'
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (options) {
                        return kendo.stringify(options);
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "data",
                    total: "total",
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            "id": { type: "number" }, //Determine the field for dynamic search
                            "name": { type: "string" },
                            "isAvailable": { type: "boolean" },
                            "price": { type: "number" }
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert(e.errorThrown);
                },
                pageSize: 10,
                sort: { field: "id", dir: "desc" },
                serverPaging: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                serverSorting: true
            });

            $("#report-grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: productsDataSource,
                autoBind: true,
                scrollable: false,
                pageable: true,
                sortable: true,
                filterable: true,
                reorderable: true,
                columnMenu: true,
                columns: [
                    { field: "id", title: "RowNumber", width: "130px" },
                    { field: "name", title: "ProductName" },
                    {
                        field: "isAvailable", title: "Available",
                        template: '<input type="checkbox" #= isAvailable ? checked="checked" : "" # disabled="disabled" ></input>'
                    },
                    { field: "price", title: "Price", format: "{0:c}" }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```